# Convert MySQL script to SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, code-migration

I have a large MySQL set of commands in a file (script) and I need to execute it on a Microsoft SQL Server 2008. I know there are few differences in both languages, despite the fact the base SQL is the same.

Is there any way how to convert a MySQL script to one that is executable on SQL Server? Or is there any migration app that can easily take the whole MySQL server and replicate everything on SQL Server 2008?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: There are tons of conversion tools (free or commercial) out there, just [google it](http://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+to+mssql+conversion). The following one might be interesting for you as a programmer, it is free and comes with the codes:
http://gathadams.com/2008/02/07/convert-mysql-to-ms-sql-server/

Comment: Previous suggestions to this problem can be found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621682/import-mysql-database-into-a-ms-sql-server

Comment: I have taken the source code from gathadams and improve it let me know if you need it ask me about `DBscriptConverter`

Answer (score 4):

I tried [Full Convert Enterprise](http://www.spectralcore.com/fullconvert/) with quite big success. Fast, easy and it did my job. Give it a try it may help you

Comment: Doesn't seem to convert the script but converts the database itself?

Comment: I downloaded this program (Trial) but it crashes when openning.

Comment: I used to use Version 5 without any problems, at least for my task. They have added a new tool http://www.sqltran.com/. You may give it a try or contact them to help you.

Comment: @MauricioGracia I can access the link

Comment: @MauricioGracia I also can access the link

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @DaImTo in this case is a link to a Tool, I don't see what essential parts can be included of a download

Comment: @vusan yesterday when I posted the comment the page was down

Comment: this tools converts scripts or requires a database connection ?

Comment: It requires database connection, but upcoming version will also convert script dumps into live databases and vice versa.

Comment: This tool is useless in regards to MySQL .dump files, as original poster has requested.