# Convert multiple mysql scripts to sql server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert MySQL script to MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770795/convert-mysql-script-to-mssql)

I am looking for a (preferably free \ GPL) tool to convert mysql scripts to mssql (2005/08).

I am aware there are many free \ paid tools online to convert mysql databases to mssql dump scripts, but this is not the solution I require, as I have a set of 30+ mysql scripts that are used to upgrade a mysql database (ALTERs, CREATE TABLEs etc) that need converting to their mssql equivalent.

Therefore, the db -> script solution does not fit, as I require a script -> script solution.

Does such a tool exist?