# Load MySQL ".SQL Dump File" into SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert MySQL script to MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770795/convert-mysql-script-to-mssql)

I have *.sql dump file that generated from the MySQL Server using the SQL Yog tool.Please anyone tell me how to convert the MySQL *.sql dump file in to SQL Script file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [Full Convert Enterprice](http://www.spectralcore.com/fullconvert/) ?

Comment: yes i tried but i am not able to do it.I want to convert only the mysql script file to SQL script file.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer this, this may help you

```
http://superuser.com/questions/202406/convert-mysql-backup-dump-script-to-ms-sql
```